# TFS Build data from TFS_Analysis

Tags: tfs, mdx

I need to fetch all build records with following fields, BuildName, VersionNo, BuildDate & BuildStatus from TFS_Analysis. Can someone help me to write MDX query for this.

Am unable to see BuildStatus field in TFS_Warehouse DB hence trying to get it from TFS_Analysis.

Comment: Note: There is no data in tbl_analysis that does not exist in tfs_warehouse. One is built from the other.

Comment: You should be querying a list from tfs_warehouse and not the cube..

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little bit like `sql` but the way things work are a world apart from `sql`. The following is complete guess work as there is not much detail in your question!...

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[SOMEMEASUREINCUBE] ON 0
 ,
    [BuildName].[BuildName].MEMBERS*
    [VersionNo].[VersionNo].MEMBERS*
    [BuildDate].[BuildDate].MEMBERS*
    [BuildStatus].[BuildStatus].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM TFS_Analysis;
```